# Django CMS Deployment issues using Apphooks with Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, django-cms

I am trying to run a Django CMS project that i created recently. The project uses PostgreSQL for its database, and works great with the **runserver** command.

But i started having intermittent ***Bad Gateway(Nginx)*** issues when i deployed the project using **NGINX** and **WSGI**. This error was sometimes happening on the whole site *or* sometimes in the sidebar where the pages, administration, etc would show up *or* sometimes in the page or advanced page settings.

The error i was getting was as follows:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
```

So i decided to get into the details of the error and found out that this error occurs only when i am using ***AppHooks*** in the project and that too only with PostgreSql. The project worked well when i deployed it using Sqlite database.

I further tried to resolve the issue by setting `ssl = false` in the config. file of PostgreSql to see if that would change anything. It changed the error i was getting earlier as follows:

```
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

So i was wondering the reason behind this issue? Let me remind you that this error is happening only when the project is deployed and not when *runserver* is being used.

**UPDATE:**

I tried using the Django-debug-toolbar to check what sql queries are being executed during these errors and it turns out the app is working fine. Somehow the debug toolbar is slowing down the applications which is not breaking the app any more. What might be the reason for the app to not work? How can i get around this issue

Comment: How are you connecting to PostgreSQL? Is it running on the same server as nginx where your Django code is? Or is the database hosted separately (e.g. EC2 connecting to AWS RDS)? Can you share your Django settings.DATABASES (remove your PASSWORD first of course)?

Comment: Hi. i am using a locally hosted database. So my data base config is as follows:  DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'p8_2',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '********',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    },
}

Comment: what wsgi server (gunicorn/uwsgi/...) are you using and with what configuration?